# Fish Shell - can't find where "la" is defined as "ls -la"

Tags: fish

On both my Mac and Ubuntu when I type "la" in Fish Shell I receive output identical to that from "ls -la". I thought I might have defined it as a function. However, I can not find "la" being defined as a alias, abbr, or function.

I've checked .config/fish/functions, fish.prompt.fish, config.fish, which and the Fish Documentation and Commands.

What have I missed? Any thoughts on where "la" could be defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` command is your friend for this type of question:

```
$ type la
la is a function with definition
# Defined in /usr/local/share/fish/functions/la.fish @ line 4
function la --description 'List contents of directory, including hidden files in directory using long format'
    ls -lah $argv
end
```

That tells me `la` is a standard function included with the fish distribution. Fish also includes a `ll` function that does `ls -lh`.